# How can I have clearmake default to GNU compatibility mode?

Tags: gnu-make, clearcase, clearmake

In a ClearCase codebase I am (unfortunately) working on, I use

```
clearmake -C gnu
```

to build. Can I somehow make GNU the default compatibility mode, so that I don't have to remember to type the extra argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`clearmake` man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearmake.htm) includes:

> Alternatively, you can use environment variable `CCASE_MAKE_COMPAT` in a BOS file or in the environment to specify a compatibility mode.

So:

```
export CCASE_MAKE_COMPAT=gnu
```

Comment: try "cleartool man clearmake" and/or "cleartool man env_ccase"

Answer (score 1):

If the GNU make compatibility option is required for the build system, I find the most reliable way is to create a `Makefile.options` file (in the same directory as the `Makefile`) that says:

```
CCASE_MAKE_COMPAT=gnu
```

This is a [build options specification](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearmake.options.htm) file that will be read automatically when the `Makefile` is read. This should be added to the source control so it is propagated to every user using `clearmake`.

Comment: Where should this file be placed? In my home directory? In the same directory as the top-level `Makefile`?

Comment: It should be in the same directory as `Makefile` and put under source control.